# Знак после «Что, если» в начале фразы [повтор]

Tags: пунктуация

***«Что, если(.../?)»(:) (—) самые безумные сценарии, которые невозможно представить.***

В первой скобке указано, поставить «?» или «...». Какой лучше?

А после кавычек, интересно, поставить двоеточие или тире?

«Что, если(.../?)», думаю, что значит, объяснять не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала, определённым образом, надо поставить многоточие, а потом – точку, поскольку второе предложение отнюдь не имеет с прямой речью никакое дело. Вопросительный знак, как мы знаем, многоточием съедается по-быстрому, так как многоточие – обжора.

`«Что, если...». Самые безумные сценарии, которые невозможно представить.` (Вариант в простом тексте с 1-м предложением – прямой речью.)

Если же всё-таки это заголовок, то возможно, естественно, только двоеточие. Мы только его (не тире) используем в таких случаях, т. е. в заголовках: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150 (7-й пункт).

> «Что, если...»: самые безумные сценарии, которые невозможно представить

Comment: По поводу многоточия спасибо, понял. Но после «Что, если...» — что является, например, форматом ютьюб-канала — типа: «Что, если иголка врежется в планету со скоростью света», — так что двоеточие или тире, поскольку сначала пишется название формата, а потом — что будет с ним связано в видео, — нужно именно двоеточие или тире. Так что это не прямая речь, а название формата видео. Предлагаю вам дополнить ответ.

Comment: Всё, сэр. Готово.

Comment: Спасибо, принял.